# Show selected photo with Expo in Image component - React Native

Tags: image, react-native, expo

I have a profile photo field in a form. At first, the form has a placeholder `Image` that the user can click and select another one to submit with the form. When changing the `Image`, I want the new `Image` to be shown in the form. For the `Image` selection, I'm using Expo `ImagePicker` and `ImageManipulator`, which returns me the `uri`.

The problem is that when the user selects the new photo, I get a blank background inside the `Image` component. The code below shows how I'm getting, manipulating and trying to show the `Image`:

**Form**

```
render() {
    [...]
    <ProfileImageEdit
        changePicture={this._onProfileImagePicker}
        picture={this.state.photo}
        uri={this.state.photoChanged}
    />
    [...]
};

_onProfileImagePicker = async () => {
    let cameraRollPermission = await this._getCameraRollPermissionAsync();
    if (cameraRollPermission) {
        let res = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: 'Images',
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [1, 1],
            quality: 1,
            base64: false
        });

        if (!res.cancelled) {
            let fRes = await ImageManipulator.manipulate(res.uri,
                [{ resize: { width: 200, height: 200 } }],
                { compress: 0.5, format: 'png', base64: false });

            this.setState({ photo: fRes.uri, photoChanged: true });
        }
    }
}
```

**Form image component**

```
export default class ProfileImageEdit extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.uri, this.props.picture);
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.props.changePicture()}
            >
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Image
                        source={(!this.props.uri ?
                            this.props.picture :
                            { uri: this.props.picture })
                        }
                        style={styles.image}
                        blurRadius={0.4}
                    />
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do both uris look right? Did you try do remove manipulation step to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Yes, the both URIs looks fine, but only the first one works. I tried setting the second URI directly to the component, but it doens't work either. Is it possible to be related to XCode Emulator?

Comment: So just the manipulator doesn't work for you. Did you fiddle with it, for example by changing resize method arguments to original image size, or by using `jpeg` instead of `png`?

Comment: Didn't check `jpeg` instead of `png`, but using the original image size still doesn't work. I'll check for the file format.

Comment: Have yo solved your problem in the end?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass an object with **uri key** to the `Image` component.

In your code, you're missing the `uri` key in the source object, try this :

```
<Image
    source={{ uri: this.props.uri || this.props.picture }}
    style={styles.image}
    blurRadius={0.4} />
```